# User and session identification from web server search logs

Tags: http, web, log-analysis

Here i have a web server search log(transaction Logs) which contains the details such as client's ip address web page he/she has requested date and time stamp, status code and many other fields. So by using this web search log file how can i perform the user identification and session identification? can any one please help me ....

Answer (score 0):

What is a user, what is a session for you?

When is a user "identified"?

From the raw logs, user = IP, and session = all requests of one IP without major time gaps inbetween. Just parse the data accordingly, it's fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

There are various method for identifying user as well as session. A simple method for the identification of session is the timeout method. In this method a predefined threshold value is used. If the inter-arrival time between the two tcp connections is less than the threshold value then both connections are belong to the same session and if it is greater than the threshold value then the first connections belongs to the current session and the second connection belongs to the next session.